# coumn reference is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql, grails

Im getting error

```
"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column reference "date_created" is ambiguous"
```

I have a Base class that defines the `date_created` field and then all the other classes extend it.

Im makeing a set of REST controllers. All of them use

`"sqlRestriction("GREATEST(date_created, last_updated) >= ?", [fromLastUpdated])"`

All of them use the same piece of code. All the other 10 cases it works, but with the 11th case it does not work. I dont get why. Ist nearly identical to all the other cases(difference is the other columns).

Where can this issue come from?

SOLUTION

Grails domain classes allow you to have refrences to other Tables

like

```
Table2 table
```

within your domain class.
This causes the hilbernate to create a join clause between table1 and table2.

So printed out the criteria created and made small modifications to fix the issue with ambiguiti

```
"sqlRestriction("GREATEST(this_.date_created, this_.last_updated) >= ?", [fromLastUpdated])"
```

this_ is the alias given to the domain on whitch you create the criteria.

Comment: Looks like the query is accessing more than one table (join) and both of the table has the date_created table. So when create does not use the tablename alias, e.g.: table.date_created in select part of the query, pgsql has no way to figureout which tables date_created column to return, resulting in column reference in amgibious

Comment: @SudhirN I thiught that too. But its a Database table. No joins. If i do the query in PGstudio then it works, but if i use creaeCriteria in grails then i get the error.

Comment: Enable query logging, and see what sql query is being fired by hibernate